# dplyr: How to summarize results to a variable (not a table)

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to summarize some data and store the resulting value in a variable, not in a table.  So, something like this:

```
result <- filter(data, cond==TRUE) %>%
    summarize(result = col1 / col2) %>%
    RETURN_COL(result)
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Could you add a reproducible example and the desired output?

Comment: If you mean just selecting one column from the output, you could pipe into `select` from `dplyr`..

Comment: @PeterDee that will make it a one column tbl. OP cld `%>% .$result` to get it into a vector.

Comment: This seemed to work for me, though not the most elegant:
`result <- ( filter(data, cond==TRUE) %>%summarize(result = col1 / col2))$result`  
In other words, use the filter... as an expression within parens, and then reference by $.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `magrittr`'s "exposition pipe-operator" which is `%$%`. Here's a reproducuble example:

```
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

result_variable <- iris %>% 
  filter(Species == "setosa") %>%
  mutate(result = Sepal.Length / Sepal.Width) %$%   # use magrittr's %$% operator to extract the result vector
  result
```

Then check the resulting vector:

```
> str(result_variable)
# num [1:50] 1.46 1.63 1.47 1.48 1.39 ...
> is.atomic(result_variable)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: I guess this means there's no straight dplyr way to do it.  Thanks for the tip.